# Spring Data neo4j 4 - Getting org.neo4j.ogm.response.model.NodeModel as a result

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Is there a way to get org.neo4j.ogm.response.model.NodeModel as results after running a particular query ?

Reason for this is I'm having dynamic properties of my node, which cannot be specify in POJO class.While I'm debugging through the SDN 4.1.1 code i've seen that all properties are there in the NodeModel under map called "properties".So if I can get that map after running a query, thats pretty much solves my problem

Answer (score 1):

NodeModel is used only internally and I would advise you not to rely on it not changing in future releases. Dynamic properties can be modelled currently as a Map with a custom converter that converts the map to/from a String.

Comment: So do we have any workaround for Dynamic Properties in SDN 4.1.1 ? or Is it still on development ? https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-555

Comment: Using a custom converter is the way to do it at the moment. DATAGRAPH-555 is pretty low on the backlog right now